# Проверка состояния NpgsqlTransaction

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

Хочу сделать откат вносимых в базу данных изменений с предварительной проверкой, что транзакция открыта.

```
NpgsqlTransaction tr;


    if (tr != null)
    {
        if (tr.Connection != null)
        {
            tr.Rollback();
            tr.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Но если транзакция закрыта, то проверка выдает ошибку

```
"tr.Connection != null" выдал исключение типа "System.ObjectDisposedException"
```

на строке

```
if (tr.Connection != null)
```

Как можно проверить состояние транзакции?

Answer (score 1):

как это делаю я:

```
/// <summary>
/// Подтверждение изменений, внесенных в БД операторами SQL. Работает только тогда, когда предварительно была открыта транзакция.
/// После подтверждения транзакция закрывается.
/// </summary>
public override void Commit()
{
    if (db == null) { return; };
    if (db.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        if ((tr != null) && (tr.Connection != null))
        {
            tr.Commit();
            tr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD**: в качестве примера:

```
using (var tr = db.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        using (var cm = db.GetSQLCommand("SELECT ......."))
        {
            using (var dr = db.ExecuteReader(cm, tr))
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    val += $"'test', ";
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
        }
        tr.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SplashScreenManager.CloseForm(false);
        tr.Rollback();
        Logger.log.Log(Logger.GetErrorInfo(ex, db.GetLastSQL()));
        ServiceWins.ShowError(ex);
        return;
    }
}
db.Close();
```

Comment: то же самое на строке "if ((tr != null) && (tr.Connection != null))" выдается ошибка, если транзакция закрыта

Comment: у вас наверное используется Npgsql 4?

Comment: @liNkiN нет 7.04. Но у меня собственная обвязка к Postgres, написанная с использованием NpgSQL. там все функции которые мне нужны и порядок взаимодействия жестко регламентирован. так что нет ситуаций, когда стартуешь транзакцию в одном месте а закрываешь в другом.

Comment: у меня эта проверка работала на Npgsql 4, а начиная с версии 5 на этой проверке состояния транзакции выбивает ошибку.

Comment: @liNkiN, ну.... не зная полного кода не могу сказать. приведите пример полного цикла и проверьте свои версии библиотеки. В принципе могу поделиться исходником плагина, который написал для себя. может поможет.